# Highcharts yAxis max not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Anyone know why the yAxis still goes up to 15 despite the max value being set to 14? I tried playing around with `startOnTick` and `maxPadding` and didn't get very far.

http://jsfiddle.net/sag8W/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {                
                type: 'line'
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0, 
                max: 14
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            maxPadding: 0.02,
            series: [                                                           
                    {name: "2013/10/10",
                    data: [5.0, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0]},                                                          
                    {name: "2014/01/10",
                    data: [4.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0]}                                                                                               
            ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to set the [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval). For some funky reason it is trying to divide the 15 points you have evenly into ticks (0 to 14 is 15 points) and it doesn't want to end on an odd value of ticks so it rounds up. This is all supposition. Anyway, try this:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0, 
        max: 14,
        tickInterval: 2
    },
```

Answer (score 7):

This problem bugged me for days, and I kept hitting this page with Bing. Anwer here has been helpful, but the issue in my side was fixed following another sample, since I had static tick to set.

Here is something similar to my final result (though it can be set dynamic);

```
    yAxis: {
        tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
            return positions;
        }
    },
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/

hope this helps.

Comment: I used the same tip, I had two yAxis and wanted to align them correctly and have the same amount of ticks

Comment: This also helped me with two yAxis, none of the other solutions seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks this works great for aligning two Y axes of different scale.